# Firebase and GCP Cloud Tasks for scheduled posting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-tasks

I am looking to integrate an automated posting service in my firebase application. The users will create a post with a desired posting time from the client application which will be added to my Firestore database.

I would like to be able to create a Cloud Task to actually add the post to the client dashboard at the desired time, which could be weeks/months in the future.

Is a cloud function Firestore trigger that creates a cloud task the best implementation?

I know that Cloud Scheduler/ Pub/Sub /App Engine is normally the flow recommended for functions run on a normal schedule, i.e once daily/weekly. But I am looking to allow my users to specify the exact time they want their post to be sent.

Is my thinking to use Cloud Tasks correct?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: You can also use Cloud Composer to schedule tasks

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it! Does this current implementation make any sense?

Answer (score 2):

I think that best approach is to use the Cloud Functions for Firebase client SDKs that will let you call functions directly from a Firebase app. To call a function from your app in this way, write and deploy an HTTPS Callable function in Cloud Functions, and then add client logic to call the function from your app. Then, if you want to schedule functions to run at specified times, use functions.pubsub.schedule().onRun() This method creates a Pub/Sub topic and uses Cloud Scheduler to trigger events on that topic, ensuring that your function runs on the desired schedule.

Comment: I know with Cloud Tasks I can create up to 1 million tasks per month for free (which is extremely generous) but with Cloud Scheduler I am less familiar with the limits. Because it sounds like in that implementation I would have to create a ton of cloud functions correct? I am a little less familiar with how cloud scheduler works, beyond if I simply wanted to run a single function on a recurring basis (daily, weekly, etc)

Comment: You will not write ton of cloud functions, you will write only one on cloud functions for Firebase. You app will call it whenever a client want to push a new post to the dashboard. If he decides to schedule an asynchronous post later on a specific time then you can schedule it on Cloud Tasks. Cloud Functions works fine with Cloud Tasks.